# Where does the "I brake for" idiom come from?

Tags: idioms

I am familiar with how *I brake for* is being used nowadays, but am puzzled as to where this idiom comes from.

I can imagine a possible origin, say a particularly popular campaign where stickers with a specific "I brake for…"  message were given, but haven't been able to find anything about this.

Comment: Surely you mean *brake*, not *break*.

Comment: If you use the phrase,"I brake for. . ." you will have greater success:-)

Answer (score 9):

First off, note that the idiom is "*I **brake** for…*", not "*I break for…*".

I imagine it's a reference to cautionary signs placed on the back of certain vehicles. For example, in the US, it's common to see signs like this on school buses or service vehicles:

> This vehicle stops at all railroad crossings
>
> This vehicle stops at all red lights
>
> This vehicle makes frequent stops

So a  cautionary sign like

> I brake for squirrels

Would be superficially similar—warning others that the vehicle may make a sudden stop if a squirrel happens to cross the road—although it's primary goal is to alert others to the driver's special love of squirrels.

This was later extended to "*I brake for **X***" where ***X*** is anything the driver feels special affection for or attraction to even if there is little or no possibility of encountering it while driving (e.g. "*I brake for smurfs*").

The cautionary sense of the idiom may still apply, for example in the bumper sticker "*I brake for [tailgaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailgating)*", which clearly does not indicate any kind of affection.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this originated sometime in the 1980's (I don't have a specific reference other than memory) with "I brake for children" becoming a fad ("Baby on board" followed soon after.).

Numerous wags then ran with it to create hundreds of variations.

Comment: It might be even a bit earlier. In 79 the New York magazine cites bumper stickers with "I brake for" http://books.google.fr/books?id=8-ACAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA58&dq=%22i+brake+for%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=6IGBUZ6HLOybyAGMioCABg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwADigAQ#v=onepage&q=%22i%20brake%20for%22&f=false

Comment: I'm sure it's earlier. I remember a neighbor of ours having an "I brake for..." bumper sticker in the early 70s. It was a more serious one, though, not something like I BRAKE FOR YARD SALES. I think the comedic ones came a little later.

Comment: Busker Jake Woods sold "I Brake for Jake" stickers in Ann Arbor, MI in 1973: http://blog.mlive.com/annarbornews/2007/09/shaky_jake.html There could be something older still.